# Adding image to html link attributes

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

I have the below html code which open in the lightbox and this is perfectly working which shows a title, an image and a footer.

```
<a href="example.png" data-footer="The Caption of the Image" data-title="A random title"></a>
```

I need to display a logo in the place of data-title. could you please help.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] - We need to see the code where you create that lightbox, and please explain what did you try in order to implement this requirement

Comment: Hi alon. I was tring to implement an image gallery using lightbox. I was attempting to put a logo on the header data-title. Thanks for your effort to review this. Finally I found the answer as below.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself. Just posting if this could be of help to someone else.

```
<a href="example.png" data-footer="The Caption of the Image" data-title="<img src='imgage.png'>"></a>
```

In above I have placed the `<img>` tag in the data-title just as you would link to an image.